# DOMNode could not be converted into a string

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, screen-scraping

```
<?php
// try this html listing example for all nodes / includes a few getElementsByTagName options:

$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. "http://website.com";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);

// example 1:
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$album = $elements->item(1);

echo $album;
```

How am I able to convert this into data that I can output to the screen? It says I cannot convert into a string. I have read that the `DOMnode` doesn't function like an array, but it makes a `DOMNodeList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the examples from this page

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php

Use

```
$album->nodeValue
```